# Php preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

This function doesn't work:

```
function remove_ul($ul) {
    $ul = preg_replace('/<ul id="general-nav">/', '<ul class="nav">', $ul, 1);
    $ul = preg_replace('/</ul>/', '<li class="blank"></li></ul>', $ul, 1);
    return $ul;
}
```

I think because of repeating `/` on line with `</ul>`

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Read about [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
$ul = preg_replace('/</ul>/', '<li class="blank"></li></ul>', $ul, 1);
```

with:

```
$ul = preg_replace('/<\/ul>/', '<li class="blank"></li></ul>', $ul, 1);
```

Or try:

```
$ul = preg_replace('#</ul>#', '<li class="blank"></li></ul>', $ul, 1);
```

Because in your code, you have specified the delimiter `/` and then using `</ul>`, there is conflict, you need to either escape the delimiter with `\` or use `#` as delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the slash in the second expression (`/<\/ul>/`). If your query becomes more complex, you might have to use a capturing group as well (parentheses).

Oh and parsing html with regex is evil. In before the XHTML Regex bandwagon storms this post. :)